# Error while grunt test regarding tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I implement tooltip in my angular project but my project gives an error on grunt test as:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip()')
```

My code to implement tooltip:

In Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

and in html:

```
<div class="rating" data-toggle="tooltip">
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: `'[data-toggle="tooltip"]'` is this correct?

Comment: Did you included `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` ?

Comment: yes both are included

Comment: on grunt serve it executes fine and i can use tooltip but in grunt test it fails

Comment: Look at the configuration of your test runner. Do you have a `karma.conf.js` file?

Comment: In this file you specify a list (or a pattern) of files to load for the tests. Jquery, bootstrap and angular should be linked here as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92268/discussion-between-michael-p-bazos-and-rajat-nigam).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Actually I missed to include bootstrap/tooltip.js in karma

Answer (score 0):

For the record, OP was here missing bootstrap tooltip plugin from his karma configuration.

Karma configuration file, usually `karma.conf.js`, contains the declaration of the files or patterns to load for the tests. For example:

```
// Inside Karma configuration object
files: [
    'bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    // ...
    app/*.js
]
```